# AWS cli s3api put-bucket-tagging not recognizing my TagSet

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I'm using the following aws cli command.  I've looked over it time after time and can't figure out what is wrong with the command.

```
aws s3api put-bucket-tagging --bucket s3://****edited**** --tagging TagSet=[{Key=Name,Value=FHWA_Packaging_Logs},{Key=Project,Value=FHWA_Processing},{Key=Team,Value=Production}]
```

I get the following error:

```
Unknown options: TagSet=[Key=Name,Value=FHWA_Processing,Key=Team], TagSet=[Key=Name,Value=FHWA_Processing,Value=Production], TagSet=[Value=FHWA_Packaging_Logs,Key=Project,Key=Team], TagSet=[Value=FHWA_Packaging_Logs,Key=Project,Value=Production], TagSet=[Value=FHWA_Packaging_Logs,Value=FHWA_Processing,Key=Team], TagSet=[Value=FHWA_Packaging_Logs,Value=FHWA_Processing,Value=Production], TagSet=[Key=Name,Key=Project,Value=Production]
```

What is wrong with the command?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The documentation in Amazon is incorrect so if you copy their example you will not be able to run the command.  There were two things wrong with the CLI command:

1) There should not be s3:// in front of the bucket name.

2) There should be quotes around the TagSet i.e. "TagSet=[{Key=xxxxx,Value=ddddd}]" (this is not in the AWS documentation).

Comment: aws s3api put-object-tagging --bucket teradata-proj-bucket --key sales-records/Elastic_Cache_WS.txt --tagging "TagSet=[{Key=xxxxx,Value=ddddd}]"

Comment: not working for me-- aws s3api put-object-tagging --bucket preprod-adwemr-dev-us-east-1 --key AXD_M/merge_1/part-00000-10b98444-ecc9-4140-851b-2499bf9c65cd-c000.snappy.parquet --tagging "TagSet=[{Key=Tag,Value=True}]" -- error : No parent directory or file

Comment: YES!! the documentation uses single quotes in the example, but it should be double quotes around the shorthand syntax of the tagging structure.

Comment: Can you set the tags for specific folder in a bucket? I want to set the value of specific folder in bucket.

Answer (score 0):

I used this solution to tag a bucket from a bash script:

```
customer="customername"
awsbucket="bucketname"
tag="TagSet=[{Key=Customer,Value=$customer}]"
aws s3api put-bucket-tagging --bucket $awsbucket --tagging $tag
```

I had to put the TagSet section in a separate variable for the tagging to work.